# How Do input ssatbles into Cassandra after generating using java parser

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cql3, cqlsh

I have a Java parser code Im running in `Eclipse` to generate 1GB of data and put in `sstable` format.  Once complete how do I load `sstables` into my `keyspace` and `cluster` from terminal on windows machine. My `cluster` is running on my local machine.

My terminal

```
path = C:\program files\datastaxcommunity\apache-cassandra\bin>
```

The command I attempt to run from terminal `path = sstableloader ip address> data\KeyspaceName\TableName`

The Error I receive: `"The system cannot find the file specified."`

Is my `sstableloader` statement correct?

Should I run `sstableloader` from a different path?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my formatting...

Answer (score 1):

The command line for `sstableloader` should be:

```
sstableloader -d <ip_address> <path to sstables>
```

It looks to me like you are missing the `-d` so the loader is trying to interpret your ip address as the sstable location.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Cassandra version ?

Since the latest minor versions (for 2.1, 2.2 and 3.x), COPY FROM command of cqlsh does a pretty decent job to load data from CSV or comma separated files. You should give it a try if you have only 1Gb worth of data to load. The related JIRAs:

1. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9302
2. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9303

Comment: Thanks great point @doanduyhai,  However Im running this test application for practice and REALLY want to learn how sstableloader works, for future work and applications. I completely understand the copy from command.